# Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|23.57.214.140|:443... failed

Tags: software-installation, java, jdk, oracle

I am running the following command

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

however I am receiving the following error

```
Downloading Oracle Java 7...
--2015-03-10 08:13:35--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u76-b13/jdk-7u76-linux-i586.tar.gz
Connecting to 10.226.33.153:6050... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily

Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 23.57.214.140
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|23.57.214.140|:443... failed: Connection refused.
download failed
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

However i am able to get updates using `sudo apt-get update` which was possible after setting my proxy ip:port in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80proxy` file, but it seems it is connecting to a bad url. So I am guessing this is not a proxy related issue.

I have tried purging and retrying the installation - it is again giving the same error.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using proxy, try to add -E before apt-get and it will force  environment to use proxy:

```
sudo -E apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Comment: Great, worked like a charm for me!

Answer (score 2):

You need to redirect HTTPS to your proxy too, add this to your /etc/apt/apt.conf:

```
Acquire::HTTP::proxy "http://127.0.0.1:3128";
Acquire::HTTPS::proxy "http://127.0.0.1:3128";
```